# get distinct persian month from timestamp in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, farsi

I need to get distinct **persian** month from the timestamp field in mysql table.
this is my query:

`` select distinct month(startTime) from times where subset_id='$subset_id' ORDER BY `id` DESC ``

but it returns a distinct Gregorian year and I can`t use it...
how can I solve this?

Comment: MySQL only supports Gregorian calendar. Everything else needs to be custom coded. [This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlpersiandat/) shows up in my search engine.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Consider handling conversions in application code

Answer (score -1):

in case of timestamp you will get month from this line

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime), '%m')
```

finally your query is

```
select 
    distinct DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime), '%m')
from times where subset_id='$subset_id' ORDER BY `id` DESC
```